# JSON ParsesError 757

Tags: ruby, json

In my Rails app, I'm trying to run JSON.parse on the contents of a JSON file and am getting the error

```
JSON::ParserError: 757: unexpected token at 'tep 5",
          "position": 8,
          "ancestry": "2482/2483/2484/2485/2486/2487/2488/2489"
        }
```

When I look at my JSON, I see the following:

```
 {
          "id": 2490,
          "name": "Step 5",
          "position": 8,
          "ancestry": "2482/2483/2484/2485/2486/2487/2488/2489"
        }
```

Any ideas why it is incorrectly parsing the string "Step 5"?

Comment: Try to parse that JSON as a string literal (it works fine for me). Then compare whatever you read from file with that literal, probably something is messed up on the reading step.

Comment: Run this:  `p File.read('your_json_file.json')` and post the part where the error is.

Comment: The only way I can get close to your error message is if I do: `JSON.parse 'tep5'` =>
`JSON::ParserError: 757: unexpected token at 'tep5'`  However, the quotes in your error are different.  Did you copy and paste the error?  Or, did you hand write the error message?

Comment: @7stud I copy and pasted the error

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue I was experiencing is specific to using AWS S3.

Previously, this is how I would try to parse the data:

s3 = AWS::S3.new(:access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'])
    key = "logs/" + self.id.to_s + ".json"
    project_json = []

```
obj = s3.buckets[ENV['AWS_BUCKET']].objects[key]
if obj.exists?
  # get the current log file if it exists and append to it
  obj.read do |data|
    project_json = data
  end
end
```

I got rid of the error by removing the do code for obj.read:

```
if obj.exists?
  # get the current log file if it exists and append to it
  project_json = JSON.parse(obj.read)
end
```